# Sikuli 1.1 making a new Region from an existing Region

Tags: python, sikuli, sikuli-script

Im trying to reuse predefined regions but I get Nonetype error when assigning it to a new variable using `sikuli.setW()`. Here's my code:

```
import math
import sikuli

self.screen_reg = sikuli.Screen(0)
self.monitor_reg = self.screen_reg

self.leftreg = sikuli.Region(
    self.monitor_reg.x,
    self.monitor_reg.y,
    int(math.floor(self.monitor_reg.w/2)),
    self.monitor_reg.h)

self.rightreg = sikuli.Region(
    self.monitor_reg.x + int(math.floor(self.monitor_reg.w/2)),
    self.monitor_reg.y,
    int(math.floor(self.monitor_reg.w/2)),
    self.monitor_reg.h)

self.leftreg.highlight(3) <=== working

self.quarter = self.leftreg.setW(int(math.floor(self.leftreg.w/2)))

self.quarter.highlight(3) <====== didnt work; 

error: NoneType object has no attribute highlight
```

If I `print type(quarter)`, it returns `NoneType`.

If I change it into these:

```
self.leftreg.highlight(3)
self.leftreg.setW(int(math.floor(self.leftreg.w/2)))
self.leftreg.highlight(3)
```

It works fine. What am I missing? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

*> What am I missing?*

An object method may not have **return type**.

Here is excerpt from [Sikuli source code](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-2014/blob/bc12c2231b7150651f4c5f638e127a235720f62d/API/src/main/java/org/sikuli/script/Region.java)

```
  public void setW(int W) {
    w = W > 1 ? W : 1;
    initScreen(null);
  }
```

Return type of setW is **void**. That is it **returns nothing**, while you expected that it returns a Region.

A correct way to do what you want would be:

```
self.quarter = Region(self.leftreg) # this constructs a new region
self.quarter.setW(int(math.floor(self.leftreg.w/2)))  # and this resizes it
```